# How to link executable to dylib to make the program relocable - preferable using cmake

Tags: macos, cmake, dynamic-linking, dyld

I have a simple application that creates dylib and executable and links the 2 of them togather

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.4)
project (SampleApplication)
add_library(SampleSharedLibrary SHARED some.cpp)
add_executable(SampleApplication main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SampleApplication SampleSharedLibrary)
```

The problem is that when I copy the files to other directory

```
cp bin/* other_directory/
```

it stops working with error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libSampleSharedLibrary.dylib
>   Referenced from: /some_path/other_directory/./SampleApplication
>   Reason: image not found
>   Abort trap: 6

Other informations:

> cmake version 3.7.2
>
> otool -D libSampleSharedLibrary.dylib
>
> libSampleSharedLibrary.dylib:
>
> @rpath/libSampleSharedLibrary.dylib

I did some googling and I just can't find a way to achieve this in cmake - either I'm using wrong properties or maybe I don't get the syntax right. I found some posts that adviced using instal_name_tool but I would rather stick to just cmake as I think it should be doable just in cmake. I figured out the solution should be to either use "@executable_path" (or @loader_path) as install_name in dylib, or stick to rpath in dylib and add rpath to executable with "@executable_path"

So my question is how to create in cmake relocatable dylib and executable pair. A working cmake code example would be perfect. If you are fluent in this area and you can find a few ways to do it I would appreciate if you listed them with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I'm putting this answer out here for those that will stumble upon the same problem so that they don't end up spending hours on the problem like I did.

Since you are on macOS, add the following lines before the `add_library` and `add_executable` lines.

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

For a solution that works for both Linux and macOS, Use the following instead:

```
if(UNIX)
    if(APPLE)
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
    endif()
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
endif()
```

To alter the path relative to your executable (e.g. to use the `lib` directory), simple append the path to the exisiting one. E.g. `@loader_path/lib` and `$ORIGIN/lib` etc...